# Use Comparable Interface to Sort a Generic Linked List

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, comparable

I want to sort my self implemented Linked List Using Comparable Interface with Java .I need to implement the compareTo method :
Here is the code for my class ListElement :

```
 public class ListElement implements Comparable<ListElement> {
    public Object wert;
    public ListElement nachFolger;

    public ListElement(Object wert , ListElement nachFolger) {
        this.wert=wert;
        this.nachFolger=nachFolger;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ListElement a) {
        if(this.nachFolger.wert - a.wert) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But I get an error , any recommendations ?

Comment: You can't subtract one `Object` object from another. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `if(this.nachFolger.wert - a.wert)` does not return `boolean`. And since those fields are `Object`s, you cannot subsctract them.

Comment: `wert` needs to be `Comparable` otherwise you need to use a `Comparator`

Comment: Also that compareTo function will only return equals or greater than, but never smaller than

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to subtract to references of type `Object`.

Your element type should implement `Comparable`:

```
public class ListElement<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<ListElement<T>> {
    public T wert;
    public ListElement<T> nachFolger;

    public ListElement(T wert, ListElement<T> nachFolger) {
        this.wert=wert;
        this.nachFolger=nachFolger;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ListElement<T> a) {
        return wert.compareTo(a.wert);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the elements are the same, should it compare the next one??

Comment: @PeterLawrey possibly. It's not clear from the question if `ListElement` is the entire implementation of the linked list, or just a single link.

Comment: ListElement is the type of objects that will be contained in my Linked List , The class Of My LinkedList is called Liste , I implemented all the required methods there s.a : addFirst() addLast delete etc ...

Answer (score 0):

In Java, subtract operation only applies to numeric literals (and auto-unboxed numeric objects). As you are trying to use it on non numeric `Object` type, you are getting the error. If you want to compare two `wert` values, you can do the following:

- Change the type to `number` from `Object` so that you can compare, e.g.:

  ```
  public Object wert;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(ListElement a) {
      return wert.compareTo(a.wert);
  }
  ```
- Change the type to `Comparable` so you can use `compareTo` on two `wert` objects

  ```
  public Comparable wert;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(ListElement a) {
      return wert.compareTo(a.wert);
  }
  ```

Comment: I Just did that , but I get an error in the main function when calling Collections.sort(myList) , should I call something else ?

Comment: Is `myList` of type `ListElement` ?

Comment: No myList is of type Liste

Comment: Liste class has one attribute LIstElement startElement which is the head of the list aswell as the linked list fucntions s.a : addfirst delete etc ..